# Add time to javascript clock

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to add a specified time to a javascript clock and have it keep updating. I have managed to chuck the below together.

```
    function leadTimer(leadTime) 
    {
      var d1 = new Date (),
      d2 = new Date ( d1 );
      d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes() + leadTime );
      currentHours = d2.getHours();
      currentMins = d2.getMinutes();
      // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
      var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
      // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
      currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
      // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
      currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;
      if (currentMins<=9) { currentMins="0"+currentMins; }
      if (currentHours<10) { currentHours="0"+currentHours; }
      $("#result").empty();
      $("#result").html(currentHours + ":" + currentMins + " " + timeOfDay)
      setInterval('leadTimer(leadTime)',10000)
}
```

I figured that the `setInterval` would just use the current value for `leadTime` but I just get an error saying `leadTime` is undefined.

Ultimately I would like to be able to call on this to keep a clock ticking over depending on what the user selects.

Comment: maerics has your fix. When you pass a string to *setInterval* it is evaluated in the global scope as if by `new Function()`, so *leadTime* is undefined. By passing a function you can keep a closure to variables defined in a local scope so when the function is called, they're available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it; [the preferred way to use `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) is to give it a function as the first argument, so try changing your last line to this instead:

```
setInterval(function(){leadTimer(leadTime)}, 10000);
```

Comment: +1 And clarification: The reason why the code in the post doesn't work is that the *the code in the string supplied is not evaluated in the current lexical context of the function*, while the closure (as used in this answer) does bind to the [[scope chain]] containing `leadTime` (a parameter in the enclosing function).

Comment: That kind of works, I think I have a problem somewhere else. On an onload event I call leadTimer(20). Then I have a button that has +10 this changes the timer to +10 but flicks back to the +20 minute time for a few seconds and flicks back again.

Comment: @user505055: it sounds like you've got two conflicting functions which are repeatedly updating the "result" element (a race condition of sorts).  A simple fix would be to make "leadTime" a global variable instead of a function argument and have the button click (and other widgets) just update its value.  There are better ways that a global but that should be easiest, you might want to increase the frequency of the display function too...